# Instance variable NSArray not updated correctly in Swift 2 - xCode 7.2

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, swift2

My message object has a to, a from and a content variable. I'm creating a page to display a tableView with the unique conversation history. Meaning just names and profile pictures of the people he exchanged messages with. To do this I made a NSArray variable where I append the data in the loadData function to then display them on the table. My Parse query returns two objects, however when I print the resultData array count it prints 0 and the reloadData then of course doesn't work. However, adding a print statement line after I append a result object to the array in the loadData() function, that works and prints correctly twice which means the NSArray is just not updating. Anybody knows why?

This is my code :

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Parse

class MessagesController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{


    @IBOutlet weak var loadingIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    var resultData:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
    var users = [String]()

    func loadData(){


        loadingIndicator.hidden = false
        loadingIndicator.startAnimating()

        resultData.removeAllObjects()

        var counter = 0
        let user = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId
        let checkConversationsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "(to = '\(user!)') OR (from = '\(user!)')")
        let checkConversationsQuery = PFQuery(className: "Messages", predicate: checkConversationsPredicate)
        checkConversationsQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
            if let objects = objects {
                for object in objects {
                    if (object.valueForKey("to") as? String) == user {
                        //check if from is in the list yet. If not, add him.
                        var isDuplicate = false
                        let from = object.valueForKey("from") as! String
                        for one in self.users {
                            if one == from {
                                isDuplicate = true
                            }
                        }

                        //if it's not a duplicate add to our array of users
                        if !isDuplicate
                        {
                            let userQuery = PFUser.query()
                            userQuery?.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: object["from"] as! String)
                            userQuery?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (users, error ) -> Void in
                                if let users = users {

                                    for user in users{
                                        let followed = user as! PFUser
                                        self.resultData.addObject(followed)
                                        self.users.append(followed.objectId!)
                                        counter++

                                    }
                                }


                            })

                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        //check if to is in the list yet, if not add him.
                        var isDuplicate = false
                        let to = object.valueForKey("to") as! String
                        for one in self.users {
                            if one == to {
                                isDuplicate = true
                            }
                        }

                        //if it's not a duplicate add to our array of users
                        if !isDuplicate
                        {
                            let userQuery = PFUser.query()
                            userQuery?.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: object["to"] as! String)
                            userQuery?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (users, error ) -> Void in
                                if let users = users {

                                    for user in users{
                                        let followed = user as! PFUser
                                        self.resultData.addObject(followed)
                                        self.users.append(followed.objectId!)
                                        counter++

                                    }
                                }


                            })

                        }

                    }

                }

                 //reload data
                    print(self.resultData.count)
                    print(counter)
                    let array:NSArray = self.resultData.reverseObjectEnumerator().allObjects
                    self.resultData = NSMutableArray(array: array)
                    self.tableView.reloadData()

            }


            if counter == 0 {
                //Handle no results
            }
        }

        loadingIndicator.hidden = true
        loadingIndicator.stopAnimating()




    }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    }



    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

        self.loadData()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

          }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return resultData.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let cell:ConversationCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ConversationCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ConversationCell
        let user:PFUser = self.resultData.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFUser

        cell.profileId = user.objectId!



        let name = (user.objectForKey("firstName") as! String) + " " + (user.objectForKey("lastName") as! String)
        cell.name.text = name

        if user.objectForKey("profilePicture") != nil {
            if let profilePicture = user.objectForKey("profilePicture") as? PFFile {
                profilePicture.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (data, error) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {
                        let profileImage = UIImage(data: data!)
                        cell.profilePicture.image = profileImage?.rounded?.circle
                    }
                })
            }
        }
        else{
            cell.profilePicture.image = UIImage(named: "profile_picture_yellow.png")!.rounded?.circle
        }





        return cell
    }


    @IBAction func backButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {});
    }

}
```

Comment: You have a debugger. A wonderful debugger. Debug! Set a breakpoint and walk through the whole operation line by line and see what's happening. You can see the values of variables as they are set. You can see what lines are executed and in what order. Answer your own question. Figure it out yourself!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock was updating the array after I reloaded the user data, so I changed it with

```
do{
                                let users = try userQuery?.findObjects()
                                for user in users!{
                                    let followed = user as! PFUser
                                    self.resultData.addObject(followed)
                                    self.users.append(followed.objectId!)
                                    counter++

                                }
                            }
                            catch let err{
                                print(err)
                            }
```